# Override SCSS variables in PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, sass, primereact

How can I override some default values from primereact e.g. the primary color?

I read that i have to override the values by adding the following code in the proviced override.scss

```
:root {
  --primaryColor: green;
  --primaryTextColor: #ffffff;
  --panelContentBorder: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
```

Unfortunately, my changes are not applied when working with e.g. a button-class (which is working with the primary color). I also read that the overrides must happen **before** the actual class is created.

How can I do that? Do I need to run a SCSS-command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to overwrite SCSS/SASS/LESS variables in general you could do the following (The process does also work with less instead of .scss)

1. Create a new .scss file
2. Instead of directly including the frameworks (doesnt matter which one you use) .scss include your OWN created .scss file (step 1)
3. Import the framework's .scss file in your own, custom .scss file
4. Compile your own .scss file using e.g. node-sass

Example of your own .scss file

```
@import "node_modules/path_to_the_libaries_scss_file.scss";

// Overwrite colors like this:
$primary-color: #ff5b00;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my remember, You can override variables in overrides/_layout_variables.scss or overrides/_theme_variables.scss files. Also you may need to upgrade your version to the latest.

Comment: Let me check on my previous project. In the meantime, can you use !important ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override variable for some more specific rule

e.g.

```js
:root {
  --primaryColor: green;
  --primaryTextColor: #ffffff;
  --panelContentBorder: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}

.somePage {
  --primaryColor: blue;
  // So primaryColor will be blue for all rules in scope of .somePage
}
```